# What is the source for this Ibn Ezra on miracles

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, miracle, avraham-ibn-ezra

A rabbi wrote on Facebook that according to the Ibn Ezra the belief in miracles derogates from the perfection of God. The rabbi explains:

> Accordingly, we do not rely on supernatural miracles to explain the
> world and its nature. As the Ibn 'Ezra taught, rather than make HaShem
> great, that actually puts him down, as it suggests that HaShem's is
> less than perfect, that He'd need to break His own laws to tinker with
> His Creation.

I am not asking whether this statement is true. The rabbi I cite is a true scholar but he does not cite the source and I would like to know what is the source for this Ibn Ezra.

Comment: Have you tried asking him via FB?

Comment: @Harel13 Yes. He doesn't know the source.